# Django API REST Framework : Generate a string based on CreateAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking to use Django API REST Framework in my web application but I get an issue in my project.

In my application, I fill a Django form in order to register a new person in my database.

My model looks like :

```
class Individu(models.Model):

    NumeroIdentification = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, verbose_name='Numero Identification physique', unique=True)
    Civilite = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=CHOIX_TITRE, verbose_name='Civilité')
    NomJeuneFille = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nom de jeune fille', blank=True)
    Nom = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nom de famille')
    Prenom = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    Sexe = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CHOIX_SEXE, verbose_name='Sexe')
    Statut = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CHOIX_STATUT, verbose_name="Statut civil")
    DateNaissance = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    VilleNaissance = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    PaysNaissance = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays de naissance')
    ...
```

The field `NumeroIdentification` is `Null` but when I submit my form and I am redirected to the next template, I have this function :

```
def Identity_Individu_Resume(request, id) :

    personne = get_object_or_404(Individu, pk=id)

    obj = Individu.objects.filter (
                                        Prenom=personne.Prenom, 
                                        Nom=personne.Nom, 
                                        DateNaissance=personne.DateNaissance, 
                                        VilleNaissance=personne.VilleNaissance
                                        )

    if obj:
        sc_obj = obj[0] #check if multiple objects are there, means obj[1]

        #Man = 1 / Woman = 2
        sex_number = []
        if personne.Sexe == 'Masculin' :
            sex_number = 1
        else :
            sex_number = 2

        #Get birthday
        birthyear_temp = str(personne.DateNaissance.year)
        birthyear_temp2 = str(birthyear_temp.split(" "))
        birthyear = birthyear_temp2[4] + birthyear_temp2[5]

        #Get birthmonth
        birthmonth_temp = personne.DateNaissance.month
        if len(str(birthmonth_temp)) == 1 :
            birthmonth = '0' + str(birthmonth_temp)
        else :
            birthmonth = birthmonth_temp

        #Get birthcity
        birth_city = personne.VilleNaissance

        #Get random number :
        key_temp = randint(0,999999)
        if len(str(key_temp)) == 1 :
            key = '00000' + str(key_temp)
        elif len(str(key_temp)) == 2 :
            key = '0000' + str(key_temp)
        elif len(str(key_temp)) == 3 :
            key = '000' + str(key_temp)
        elif len(str(key_temp)) == 4 :
            key = '00' + str(key_temp)
        elif len(str(key_temp)) == 5 :
            key = '0' + str(key_temp)
        else :
            key = key_temp

        NumeroIdentification = str(sex_number) + str(birthyear) + str(birthmonth) + str(birth_city) + '-' + str(key)

        #Update NumeroIdentification
        personne.NumeroIdentification = NumeroIdentification
```

Now I'm trying to implement this function in my API REST.

I have a file named `serializer.py` :

```
class IndividuCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta :
        model = Individu
        fields = [
            #'id',
            #'NumeroIdentification',
            'Civilite',
            'Nom',
            'Prenom',
            'Sexe',
            'Statut',
            'DateNaissance',
            'VilleNaissance',
            'PaysNaissance',
            'Nationalite1',
            'Nationalite2',
            'Profession',
            'Adresse',
            'Ville',
            'Zip',
            'Pays',
            'Mail',
            'Telephone',
            #'Creation',
            #'InformationsInstitution',
            #'Utilisateur',
            'Etat',
            #'Image',
            #'CarteIdentite',
        ]
```

And `api.views.py` file :

```
from rest_framework.generics import (
    CreateAPIView,
    UpdateAPIView,
    DestroyAPIView,
    ListAPIView, 
    RetrieveAPIView,
    )


from Identity.models import Individu
from .serializers import IndividuSerializer, IndividuCreateSerializer

class IndividuListAPIView(ListAPIView) :
    queryset = Individu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividuSerializer

class IndividuCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView) :
    queryset = Individu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividuCreateSerializer

class IndividuDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Individu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividuSerializer

class IndividuUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView) :
    queryset = Individu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividuSerializer

class IndividuDeleteAPIView(DestroyAPIView) :
    queryset = Individu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IndividuSerializer
```

How I can add the part about `NumeroIdentification` Generator in my API (Identity_Individu_Resume in my software) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `create` method of `IndividuCreateSerializer` for this:

```
class IndividuCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        obj = Individu.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Identity_Individu_Resume(obj)
        return obj
```

note that in my example you will passs Individu object to `Identity_Individu_Resume` function directly without request so you need to make some modification on `Identity_Individu_Resume` function.

Comment: Wow it's a bit obscur for me. It's the first time I'm using Django API REST ^^

Comment: @Deadpool the basic idea of this method is customization creation process in to add some logic after object will be created. You can find example of serializer's create method overriding here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: Ok so I wrote your answer based on your django-rest-framework documentation and I get this issue : `Exception Type: TypeError at /api/Identity/create/
Exception Value: Identity_Individu_Resume() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

I didn't make modifications on `Identity_Individu_Resume` because I don't know if I just have to remove `request argument`

Comment: @Deadpool well if you cannot change `Identity_Individu_Resume` or use another function you can call it from `create` method and pass reqiest and object id: `Identity_Individu_Resume(self.context.get('request'), obj.id)`.

Comment: Yes it seems to work ;) Thank you so much ! I'm very stuck in this kind of things so I apologize :/

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use [serializermethodfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class IndividuCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    NumeroIdentification = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_NumeroIdentification(self, obj):
        request = request = self.context.get('request')
        return Individu_Resume(request, obj.id)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand really well what you do.

Comment: it is add calculated field, and i think your `Individu_Resume` return the result, it was my mistake, sorry

Comment: If I use your method, `NumeroIdentification` is always `null` after form submitting.